# SQL Extract from JSON "object"

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

So I have a requirement to extract some data from JSON store and for the most part its pretty simple with `JSONVALUE()`. However some of the stores seem to use a deeper storage method.

Some example code;

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
"N.data.-60d8249a-ed12-4f41-98f4-01c910c6b2f4": null,
"R.title": "{\"description\":\"Mr\",\"alternates\":{},\"position\":0}",
"R.gender": "{\"description\":\"Male\",\"alternates\":{},\"position\":1}",
"R.jobTitle": "{\"description\":\"Operations\",\"alternates\":{},\"position\":2}"
}'
```

What I need to do is extract the "description" aspect from each key.  For example, "R.title" would give me "Mr" etc.

Ideally I could extract a specific key each time using a parameter approach:

```
DECLARE @id nvarchar(200) = 'R.title'
SELECT  
*  
FROM OPENJSON(@json, concat('$."',@id,'"')) AS a
```

Is there a correct way to do this without doing nasty substring() methods?

Thanks!

SQL Server version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017
>   17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3  (Build 9600: )
>   (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a late answer, but I hope it helps. You need to parse the input JSON with two `OPENJSON()` calls and additional `APPLY` operator. The first `OPENJSON()` call uses the default schema to get the names for all keys in the input JSON.

Statement:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
"N.data.-60d8249a-ed12-4f41-98f4-01c910c6b2f4": null,
"R.title": "{\"description\":\"Mr\",\"alternates\":{},\"position\":0}",
"R.gender": "{\"description\":\"Male\",\"alternates\":{},\"position\":1}",
"R.jobTitle": "{\"description\":\"Operations\",\"alternates\":{},\"position\":2}"
}'


SELECT j.[key], v.description
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.[value]) WITH (description nvarchar(max) '$.description') v
```

Result:

```
-----------------------  
key         description
-----------------------  
R.title     Mr
R.gender    Male
R.jobTitle  Operations
```